# Git SHA hash and commit message

Tags: git, github

I want to store git SHA Hash and git commit message every time I **push something on github**. Can anyone tell me where is the git commit message stored locally Everytime I push something?

Comment: The commit message is stored in the commit object that is identified by the hash value and which is the thing you are pushing to your remote. I don’t understand what you want to know here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `git log` to get a list of the previous `git commit` messages? Pipe it to a text file and parse it for the required data.